Why does computing qth rooth mod q doesn’t help for fixed pairing inversion?
There are many research papers that reduce the fixed pairing inversion problems down to expoentiation inversion. I understand how computing qth roots mod q where $q=p^m$ is different from exponentiation inversion since it’s usually many to 1.
But why it doesn’t help even for finding a pairing that generate the given finite field’s element instead of the original pairing ? I was explained the following requirement for a qth root being valid, but I fail to understand it

Suppose the elliptic curve is defined over $F_p$,
the embedding degree $k$ is even, and the order of pairing is a prime $r$.
Put $m:=k/2$.
You must obtain the collect value of $h_{p^m+1,A}(Q)$
(where both $A$ and $Q$ are of order $r$).
But $h_{r,A}(Q)$ have only to be precise up to $(p^m+1)/r$ th root of the unity.
That is, instead of the correct value z, the value zu where
$u^{(p^m+1)/r}=1$ will do. This is because $u$ is eliminated in the process
to obtain $h_{p^m+1,A}(Q)$ from $h_{r,A}(Q)$.


@fgrieu Reference to your answer removed. The text I put in the question is an exact copy/paste of the email I received from the busy researcher.

I do not understand if the question is about "qth roots mod q where $q=p^m$", or something else. I can't think of any context where a "qth root mod q" appears. And when there's $p^m$ (with $m>1$) in a pairing context, it's most often to define the field, which operation are not $\bmod p^m$. You'll have to clarify the question. Providing the question that generated the quoted answer might help. Plus it's sad that we have to guess if "collect" is a meaningful word, or is a typo. If we can assume a particular paring or/and curve, please tell, or link to a reference on that.

@fgrieu the answer I received seems to be itself out of context since the question was about this paper https://pdfupload.io/docs/8453308d#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A2814%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22FitH%22%7D%2C406%5D so qth roots mod q where $q=p^m$

The question (v7) links to a paper Exponentiation Inversion Problem Reduced from Fixed Argument Pairing Inversion on Twistable Ate Pairing and Its Difficulty, in proceedings of IWSECT 2014.
That article reasons about Exponentiation Inversion without definition, as if it was a well-known problem. That's actually defined by their reference [5]: Naoki Kanayama and Eiji Okamoto, Approach to pairing inversions without solving Miller inversion, in IEEE ToIT 2011 as (verbatim)

Definition 3: (Exponentiation Inversion, EI) For an unknown element $\beta\in\mathbb F^∗_{q^k}$, assume that an integer $n$ and the value of $w:=\beta^n\in\mathbb F^∗_{q^k}$ are known. Then, the EI, or $(n,w)$-EI, is the problem of finding $\beta$ from the instance $(n,w)$.

The EI problem is related to the problem of finding an $n^\text{th}$ root of $w$ in a finite field when one exists. That other problem is easy if, with $s=q^k-1$, and $d=\gcd(s,n)$, it holds $\gcd(s,s/d)=1$. Then a solution is $x=w^{((n/d)^{-1}\bmod s)((((-s/d)^{-1}\bmod d)(s/d)+1)/d)\bmod s}$, there are $d$ solutions, and a random solution is $y^{s/d}x$ with $y$ random in $\mathbb F^∗_{q^k}$.
The authors of [5] state "the EI is generally hard" without discussion or characterization of the hard cases. They present that hardness as the reason why their reduction of some pairing inversion problems to an EI problem does not solve these pairing inversion problems. Their reduced EI problem is with $n=s/r$ and $r$ a large prime appearing only once in the factorization of $s$, thus the $n^\text{th}$ root problem is in the above easy case, with $d=n$.
That's because the authors of [5] deliberately make their EI problem finding the one solution $\beta$ to an $n^\text{th}$ root problem $x^n=w$ with unknown $x$ where the given $w$ was computed as $w:=\beta^n$. That matches the above quoted definition of EI to the letter. It makes the EI problem difficult for their $n$, because it has $n$ solutions and no way to find $\beta$ among them. That instance of EI is hard in the sense that finding a large bitstring given half it's bits is hard.
That definition of EI makes full sense when we consider e.g. side channels to break actual implementations of pairing, something [5] mentions as interesting: an attack on the implementation of the final step $w:=\beta^n$  of a pairing computation can provide extra information allowing to solve EI even when mathematically hopeless! Not coincidentally, one citation of [5] is Ronan Lashermes, Jacques Fournier and Louis Goubin's Inverting the Final Exponentiation of Tate Pairings on Ordinary Elliptic Curves Using Faults, in proceedings of CHES 2013. That article makes a clear use of the term Exponentiation Invertion to mean recovering the output of the Miller Loop before a Final Exponentiation, which they do with a fault attack.
So when we talk about reduction to an EI problem, that's not comparable to say reduction to Discrete Logarithm Problem, the factorization problem, the RSA problem, or the problem of finding an $n^{th}$ root in a finite field. EI can be a mathematically under-specified problem that no amount of computing power can solve, and that's what it is down to it's originating context.
Some papers citing [5] and with "Exponentiation Inversion" in their title, including the paper of concern to the OP in this question and the other paper an earlier one, contain no hint they use EI as a model for fault or side-channel scenarios. I'm inclined to look at such articles with suspicion.

Now to try analyze the question, it talks about

computing $q^\text{th}$ roots $\bmod q$ where $q=p^m$

That has problems:

Pairings based on BN curves and similar have output in $\mathbb F^*_{p^m}$ with like $m=12$, and that involves no computation modulo $p^m$. I guess we must read "in $\mathbb F^*_q$" rather than $\bmod q$, and that's quite different.
$\mathbb F^*_{p^m}$ has order $q-1$, thus raising to the power $q$ is the identity function. So finding $q^\text{th}$ root is returning the number which $q^\text{th}$ root is asked, and that's the only solution.

Perhaps it's asked why computing a random $n^\text{th}$ root in $\mathbb F^*_{p^m}$ is not useful to pairing inversion. If $n=q/r$ with $r$ the order of a BN curve, my explanation is: that computation is very easy (see code in my earlier answer) thus can not be much useful in a hard problem. For other values of $n$, I ask: which value?
